# Insertar datos de una tabla a otra

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`CREATE TRIGGER insert_id_tecnlogia AFTER INSERT ON tecnologia FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  INSERT INTO detalle_ingreso (idtecnologia) VALUES (idtecnologia) END;`

Al momento de agregar en la tabla tecnologia, el triggers es para que agregue el idtecnologia a la tabla detalle_ingreso. Me genera ese error: Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails .

Vale destacar que la tabla detalle_ingreso tiene que ingresar datos de dos tablas mas, idlista, idcentro. Todas estan relacionadas con foreign key.

Me podrian apoyar a validar cual seria el error de porque sucede esto, no he trabajado mucho con triggers

Answer (score 1):

El trigger debes crearlo como:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER after_tecnologia_insert
AFTER INSERT ON tecnologia
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE last_id INT;
  SET last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  INSERT INTO detalle_ingreso (idtecnologia)
  VALUES (last_id);
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Probablemente debas definir un valor predeterminado para los campos idcentro y idlista (o hacerlos NULL en la definición de tu tabla)

Comment: Idcentro , idlista e idtecnologia son llaves foráneas en la tabla detalle y en la.tabla de dónde provienen son llaves primarias, por defecto son not null. De esta manera de tu ejemplo  se agregaría solo el ID tecnología y los otros ID? Quedarian not null en esa fila de la tabla detalle ? Mi duda es como haría para que se almacene cada ID en la tabla detalle con los ID de cada tabla y se asigne un idddtalle para ese registro en conjunto, tomando en cuenta que las tablas (tecnología,lista y centro) no se insertaran al mismo tiempo

Comment: Según el manual, "Un _trigger_ es un objeto de base de datos con nombre que está asociado con una tabla y que se activa cuando ocurre un evento particular para la tabla". O sea que el trigger que creas para la tabla 'tecnologia' se activa solo cuando haces un INSERT en esa tabla. De la misma manera funcionarían triggers en otras tablas. Para que funcione de la manera que deseas y si creas un trigger en cada una de tus tres tablas, dentro del BEGIN...END de cada trigger también debes incluir un SELECT en las otras dos tablas para encontrar los valores de las claves foráneas que vas a insertar.

Comment: Para realizar esto los campos en la tabla destino (detalle) deberían de estar not null o null? La inserción de los datos a la tabla detalle no se hará de manera seguida, puede ser que cada uno de ellas se active el evento insert cada cierto tiempo y se necesito que la tabla detalle almacene cada uno de esos registros. Ejemplo: idddtalle - idtecnologia - idlista - idcentro en la misma fila en la tabla detalle

Comment: Ya que estamos hablando de claves foráneas, no debería haber inserciones que no las incluyan todas, entonces pienso que deberían ser NOT NULL y en el trigger de cada tabla incluir un SELECT que busque las otras dos claves extra que necesitas 
 ya que según tu planteamiento, el trigger inserta una de ellas: la clave foránea que acabas de crear (la más reciente)